# Battery isolator reminder for classic car

Tags: voltage, led, relay, automotive

I would like to add a small buzzer or led light to the dash of my old MGA which activates only when:

- a) the ignition is off

AND

- b) the battery switch is on. (i.e., I have forgotten to shut off the battery cut off switch.
  This is to remind me to use the cutoff switch-as a safety feature and to prevent battery drain.)

Behind the key switch, I can obviously see if the ignition is off and elsewhere I can see if the cars electrics still have a voltage. I assume some sort of relay would help do this, but unfortunately I have no clue.

Really hope someone can help.

PS I would order any parts in Europe, either eBay or conrad.com or reichelt.de.

Comment: What is the question here? You want us to design something up to your specs?

Comment: What a creative way of voiding your car's insurance!

Comment: @Dmitry, small mods like that are probably not an insurance issue with an MGA!

Comment: @BrianDrummond [Rev Wena Parry, 75, was told that stickers saying “Christ Must Be Saviour” and “Christ For Me” could be regarded as “modifications” and could invalidate her insurance policy](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-wales-south-west-wales-31064998)

Comment: You may be able to use a lights-on alarm/buzzer to do this. Have you looked into using one? It may be a little difficult if the MGA has positive earth.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I just wanted some tips. Design is nice but I also want to learn.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you for your concern. thank goodness I do not live in a country where such a tiny mod would be an insurance issue.

Comment: @Steve Thank you, I will search google and see if I can do something with that. The MGA is negative earth. I thought maybe two relays, one that switches when open and another taht switches when shut, would be possible.(NO/NC??).

Comment: coincidentally: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227836/first-time-using-integrated-circuits

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I know a person that had her car vandalized in the US Bible Belt because of a [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster) sticker so I can see the insurance company's point here. But if it's an unrelated thing it should not have an effect..

Comment: @Jaap_98 AFAIK an MGA doesn't come with a shut-off switch per standard (though I may be wrong). While the LED or buzzer aren't insurance voiding mods in Europe, many insurance companies in NL,DE,BE,etc _do_ consider the insurance void if you modify the main power circuitry, especially in the case of electric fires or accidents through loss of control or loss of sight at night.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5CMIS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Battery isolator reminder.*

If I understand your question properly this circuit will do what you require.

- If the isolator is left switched on and the ignition switch opened current will flow around the ignition switch, through R1/D1 and the buzzer and find its way back to the chassis via whatever load is on the ignition circuit. If there is no load then there will be no warning but this shouldn't matter as the battery won't be discharging.
- When the ignition switch is closed the warning circuit is shorted out.

The buzzer is optional. The resistor is required to limit the current through the LED to about 10 mA.

Comment: thank you for this. Obviously I have been overcomplicating this. forgive my ignorance but if I left out the buzzer, would the LED still work? I have ordered some led on ebay http://www.ebay.de/itm/311466435475. would I need the resitor or is the resistor there to prevent the led being on when ignition is on? Circuitlab is interesting but have not worked out how to use it;) Many thanks!!

Comment: See update - last paragraph.

Comment: great , I will try this as soon as the leds arrive in luxembourg (from HK alas..). Thank you!

Comment: I know it has been a long time but finally was able to try.

Comment: sorry it has been a long time. I have tried the above with the 12 V led but I am unable to get it working as intended. The led lights when the isolator is on and is off when it is not. all as expected. However, it also lights when the ignition is switched on, which I want to avoid. I have tried the resistor (and a potentiometer upto 10k but don't seem to get this working. Not sure what I am doing wrong. If you have any ideas, I would be really grateful. many thanks, Jaap

Comment: I'm still here! It's got to be a wiring error. The LED has to be wired _across the switch_ and not between the switch and chassis / negative. You need to identify the wire _from_ the ignition switch and wire to that. Is there a wiring diagram available for your car?

Comment: You are right and I was stupid. Have now wired up as you suggest and that works exactly as intended - many thanks!!. Am a bit concerned abut current. Without a resistor these are described as 1.8W 12V car leds. This would suggest 0.15A and an internal resistance of 80 Ohm. I am not sure if this is too much leakage or if the LED will give me enough power to be seen adding the resistor. Just waiting for some in the mail to try this out. Perhaps I will need different LEDS or alternatively a subtle beeper/buzzer. If I forget an empty battery would not be funny (but deserved I guess)

Comment: If they are rated at 12 V then they have the internal resistor. You can safely add as much resistance as you want in series to reduce the current further but, obviously, this will dim the LED. Your maths is right but a standard 5 mm LED would only need 10 to 20 mA. The unit you've purchased must have many in parallel. I'd say you're not likely to miss it as you exit the car!