# First Time Using Integrated Circuits

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, automotive, 12v

I am building a circuit for a custom application. I have an old Toyota truck, and I keep leaving the headlights on, because there is no warning buzzer!

I have designed a circuit that takes 3 inputs:
* Headlights on
* Driver's door open
* Engine off

I want to build this using integrated circuits, and have it supply 12V to a piezo buzzer when the above 3 conditions are met. Here's what I'm thinking:

[image]

Will this work? I studied electronics in college, but haven't done anything with it since!

Answer (score 2):

You've got the logic right, just need to work out the details.  This should do the job:

[image]

I have used NAND gates so I can use one as the inverter for the Engine Off condition.  The CD4023 has three 3-input NAND gates, and will work with voltages up to 15V.

[The piezo](http://www.puiaudio.com/pdf/AI-3245-TF-LW95-R.pdf) has an internal driver, and is spec'ed for operation from 3 to 28VDC.

It would be a very bad idea to connect it up this circuit up to the 12V battery directly. First of all, the 12V battery is nominally about 14V. In addition transients can be nasty on a vehicle's 12V system, with voltages rising as high as 125v for 10 ms during a [load dump](http://www.eet-china.com/ARTICLES/2003MAY/PDF/2003MAY26_POW_AN04.PDF).

This power supply circuit provides protection against negative voltages in addition to the positive spikes due to load dumps, noise, and jump starting, and keeps the voltage at 12V:

[image]

Comment: why the tantalum cap?

Comment: The original circuit I took this from, the 12V section was followed by a 7805 for a 5V circuit.  I think the tant is left over from that.  I'll remove it.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the schematic from Eagle?

Comment: @LCW Yes, both of them are.

Answer (score 1):

That circuit's power supply will fail in a load dump (45 V). C1 needs to be rated 50 V and/or you need a resistor (10..100 ohm) in series with the input. The 12 V zener D3 will put a continuous load on the battery.

However, you don't need all that complexity (although this consumes about 1 mA from VBATT when off).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcNKav.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D5 protects Q1 from transients. When Door open and Headlights are high, R1's current flows through D3 to the base of Q1. If Engine Off is also low, then Q1 will be on and the buzzer energized.

Diodes should be 1N4002 or 1N4007 or equivalent

Comment: I changed Zener D3 to 14V so it normally won't be drawing any current.  Thanks for pointing that out.